Flutter/Dart Android Emulator Text Input Widget with strange characters on Windows
During test with VSCode and Android Emulator suddenly the Text Input widget shows strange characters - I can not 100% tell the trigger, but it has to do with using backspace to delete characters ... not really sure because it happens often but randomly.
When typing "asdfg" on my PC keyboard, in the widget I get

when clicking on the emulator on screen keyboard the text is normal "asdf"
The language of the on-screen keyboard is en-de and is not changing.
I have not yet found a method to switch back to normal behavior - just shut down everything including cold boot of the emulator.
Any Idea what happens?

The same thing happened to me.
Wipe the data of the emulator and try again.
It will fix the input issue.


thanks for the hint, but this has the same effect as "cold boot" of the emulator which I would like to avoid due to long boot procedure.

Yes, but it will fix the issue
